# why the framerate become slower when using libcamera on raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, embedded-linux

I use libcamera to generate h264 stream and my android client receive it by socket

```
libcamera-vid -t 0 --width 320 --height 240 --framerate 15 --inline --listen -o tcp://0.0.0.0:10001
```

In the beginning, the framerate is good, but after some minutes, the framerate become slow.

```
#3518 (7.96 fps) exp 66503.00 ag 8.00 dg 1.00
#3519 (2.65 fps) exp 66503.00 ag 8.00 dg 1.00
#3520 (0.00 fps) exp 66503.00 ag 8.00 dg 1.00
#3521 (2.65 fps) exp 66503.00 ag 8.00 dg 1.00
#3522 (0.00 fps) exp 66503.00 ag 8.00 dg 1.00
#3523 (2.65 fps) exp 66503.00 ag 8.00 dg 1.00
#3524 (15.92 fps) exp 66503.00 ag 8.00 dg 1.00
#3525 (7.96 fps) exp 66503.00 ag 8.00 dg 1.00
#3526 (1.77 fps) exp 66503.00 ag 8.00 dg 1.00
#3527 (15.92 fps) exp 66503.00 ag 8.00 dg 1.00
#3528 (0.00 fps) exp 66503.00 ag 8.00 dg 1.00
#3529 (15.92 fps) exp 66503.00 ag 8.00 dg 1.00
#3530 (7.96 fps) exp 66503.00 ag 8.00 dg 1.00
#3531 (2.65 fps) exp 66503.00 ag 8.00 dg 1.00
#3532 (15.92 fps) exp 66503.00 ag 8.00 dg 1.00
#3533 (7.96 fps) exp 66503.00 ag 8.00 dg 1.00
#3534 (2.27 fps) exp 66503.00 ag 8.00 dg 1.00
```

Can someone tell the reason? I'm a newbee at video codec.